# Add TabularInline to my admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-admin, inline, tabular

I need some help.
I need to add the TabularInline to my admin interface because I have to insert the periodic table that has at least 100 elements.

I have in Models:

```
class ElementsTable(models.Model):
    sign = models.CharField(max_length=3,null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=False)

class ListMaterials(models.Model):
    materials = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=False)
    ElementsTable = models.ManyToManyField('ElementsTable')
```

And in Admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from italgraniti.models import *

class ElementsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ElementsTable
    extra = 3

class ElementsTableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('sign', 'name')
    inlines = [ElementsInline]

class AnalisysAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','nprova')

class ListMaterialsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('materials',)

admin.site.register(Analisys, AnalisysAdmin)
admin.site.register(ElementsTable, ElementsTableAdmin)
admin.site.register(ListMaterials, ListMaterialsAdmin)
```

but it returns:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'italgraniti.admin.ElementsTable'>: (admin.E202) 'italgraniti.ElementsTable' has no ForeignKey to 'italgraniti.ElementsTable'.
```

I would insert almost 10 tuple (sign,name) in one time..

(django 1.8, python 3.5)
**Edit**: insert entire Admin

**Edit**: i'm very sorry but i'm done some error to traslate in english admin.py and model.py. I've correct them now. I understand your solution but result anyway

```
<class 'italgraniti.admin.ElementsTabel'>: (admin.E202) 'italgraniti.ElementsTabel' has no ForeignKey to 'italgraniti.ListMaterials'.
```

Comment: Post your entire admin.py, could be an issue further down

Comment: Done,edit initial post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you accidentally put your `ElementsTable` model in quotes.

Try changing:

`ElementsTable = models.ManyToManyField('ElementsTable')`

to

`elements_table = models.ManyToManyField(ElementsTable, related_name='elencomaterialiAsElementsTable')`.

**EDIT:**

It looks like your main problem is that you are trying to Inline your ElementsTable into itself, which isn't possible. The point is that you should be able to see it in the `ElencoMateriali` admin page. I have cleaned up the code and added the feature here:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from italgraniti.models import Analisys, ElementsTable, ListMaterials, ElencoMateriali

class ElementsTableInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ElementsTable
    extra = 3

class ElencoMaterialiAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('materials',)
    inlines = [ElementsTableInline]

class ElementsTableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('sign', 'name')

class AnalisiAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'nprova')

class ListMaterialsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('materials',)

admin.site.register(Analisys, AnalisysAdmin)
admin.site.register(ElementsTable, ElementsTableAdmin)
admin.site.register(ElencoMateriali, ElencoMaterialiAdmin)
admin.site.register(ListMaterials, ListMaterialsAdmin)
```

Comment: I just changed the admin, so give it a try and let me know if it works for you.